# Trying to use dev mode deployment URL with Google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to call a function from my Google app script project, using external tools like Postman or something:

Dev Url Example:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwz......rlL1A/dev

```
function doGet() {
  console.log('do get called')
}
```

[post man Get request Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY2jo.png)

I tried including an access token both as a parameter and an Authorization header, but nothing is working for me.

I want to run the functions from external resources in development mode.

but am getting an Error with HTML:

Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1
.....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.